# Read XML in Java with XML attributes

Tags: java, xml

I want to read following XML file:

```
<RootNode>
    <Node id="1"> value1 </Node>
    <Node id="2"> value2 </Node>
    <Node id="3"> value3 </Node>
    <Node id="4"> value4 </Node>
    <Node1 id="1"> value11 </Node1>
    <Node1 id="2"> value12 </Node2>
    ...
</RootNode>
```

Now depending on the Node id I want to fetch the value. Like if the Node name is `Node` and id is `1` the value should be `value1` and if Node name is `Node1` and id is `2` then value should be `value12`.

I'm able to get the elements with name `Node` using this code:

```
try{
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Node");
}
catch(Execption e){
    e.printStacktrace();
}
```

How can I get the elements depending on the attribute(`id` in this case) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the value of id first get attribute 'id' value

```
private static String getAttributeValue(final Node node, final String attributeName) {
    Element element = (Element) node;
    return element.getAttribute(attributeName);
}
```

By this way passing node(name = 'node') and attribute name('id') to this method, this will return you the value of attribute id. Now you have the value and you have the node so you can do what ever you want :)

To iterate the node list

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
      NamedNodeMap parmAttrMap = parmList.item(i).getAttributes();
      if ((parmAttrMap.getNamedItem("id") != null)) {
         //get value of id -- parmAttrMap.getNamedItem("id");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath could help...

```
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//Node[@id=\"YOUR_VALUE_HERE\"]");
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Replace YOUR_VALUE_HERE for the required id value, and iterate through nl